# Stop css file renaming when working locally

Tags: 8, theming, css-js-aggregation

I've followed this guide to setup settings.local.php:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

And in my custom subtheme I have a stylesheet style.css which is working correctly. However when I look in the network tab in Chromium I see that the file is being renamed and loaded as the following instead of style.css

css_vUzTZgnz_vbCKVrMpGH7w6mCDpJcmKbwfvLonjhF6Yo.nbvVRORIA_VOZ9jlIN0xvyy_2wDJZdAeRBMnmfGNre0.css?poey84

Is there a way to stop this renaming using settings.local.php during development? I've tried turning off css aggregation through the GUI but I believe the changes in settings.local.php override this anyway?

Cheers

Comment: `$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;` with this in your `settings.local.php` you should be OK.  Check in the settings.php perhaps after the inclusion of `settings.local.php`, check in the `admin/config/development/performance` under performance optimization and report what you see.  Perhaps there is a module that forces this setting?

Comment: What Giorgos says. Yes, looks like you have advagg enabled. Disable it during development.

Comment: Thank, advagg was the problem. I had disabled it but it was still renaming the files. Fully uninstalling the advagg module with drupal console was the solution.